# Using IIS and not localhost:9000

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, iis, sonarqube

Currently I am trying to use sonarqube on my project for code analysis and it works fine the sonarqube webpage is showing in localhost:9000 and I am getting the results I want. But now my question is, how to launch the sonarqube webpage on an IIS rather than on local webserver, so that the webpage can be accessed from other systems as well.

I read many articles but noone has mentioned on how to launch the sonarqube webpage on IIS webserver rather than local:9000.

Is there a plugin to install or any config files to change?

To keep it simple when I run the sonarqube start.bat the sonar webpage has to launch on IIS webserver and not locahost:9000

Here is my webserver sonar.properties code

```
#Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which  
#address will be used for listening on the specified ports.  
#By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.  
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000
```

Comment: How does your `sonar.properties` File look?

Comment: From Sonarqube docs: Starting the Web Server
The default port is "9000" and the context path is "/". These values can be changed in <install_directory>/conf/sonar.properties:

Comment: Hi @Smartis, My sonar.properties are as follows..

# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
#sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000

Comment: @Vasu please put it formatted in the question.

Comment: @Smartis , Apologies i never used stack overflow so i am kind of new to posting stuff here,but now u can find the formatted code in the question itself in a better format. i coped the code from sonar.properties file

Answer (score 1):

SonarQube will not 'run' on IIS. You can configure IIS to be  a reverse proxy for it, but that's not the same.

You can install SonarQube to run as a service, which will automatically start up on machine boot, and will be accessible from other machines via its address on port 9000. This can be configured using the settings to be any available port you like.

See [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/06/04/running-sonarqube-behind-an-iis-reversed-proxy/) for reverse proxy set up.

Or install Sonar as a service on a machine, add a dns entry of sonar.mycompany.com.au. To access the results just go to sonar.mycompany.com.au:9000. This works perfectly. You don't need IIS mate, just use sonars web server to start up on machine boot - it will install as a Windows Service. You could even set it to use port 80 if you wanted to disable IIS on that machine. One thing you will need to do is setup sonar with a DB other than the one it ships with - which is for demo purposes only.

Comment: the main reason i want iis is to make sure that even other developers in my team can see the results which display on localhost/9000 when sonar.scanner completes its scanning of our code which will not be possible if the result is displayed in localhost.So u r saying if i install sonar as webservice i will be able to achieve the same?

Comment: We use that kind of setup at my dev shop. We have installed Sonar as a service on a machine, added a dns entry of sonar.mycompany.com.au. To access the results just go to http://sonar.mycompany.com.au:9000. This works perfectly. You don't need IIS mate, just use sonars web server to start up on machine boot. You could even get it to use port 80 if you wanted to disable IIS on that machine. 

One thing you will need to do is setup sonar with a DB other than the one it ships with - which is for demo purposes. We use MSSQLS. I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The SonarQube documentation about [*Securing the Server Behind a Proxy*](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Securing+the+Server+Behind+a+Proxy) has a dedicated note about IIS, which links directly to [this helpful blog post](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2016/02/configure-ssl-for-sonarqube-on-windows.html).